How to make a HTTP call from a Vue.js app that includes a list of files to upload
I need to call a Spring controller that has a @RequestPart parameter of type List<MultipartFile> and expects a list of files. The front end application is written in Vue.js and so far I have tried to use the FormData: append() method. The JS code for the call is:
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('body', etc.);
bodyFormData.append('attached_files', file_1, 'file_1.pdf');
bodyFormData.append('attached_files', file_2, 'file_2.pdf');
return axios.post(
  `url`,
  bodyFormData,
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
);

The controller is:
@PostMapping(
   path = "/upload-files",
   consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
   produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> uploadFiles(
     @RequestPart(value = "body") @Valid Request request,
     @RequestPart(value = "attached_files", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files) { ...

If I call the controller using Postman or Swagger using the label 'attached_files' for both files:

the Controller parameter files is correctly filled with a list of the two sent files. But if I make the call above through Axios, the parameter files is null.
Maybe append() is the wrong method here? Maybe I can't use Axios for what I need? Thanks in advance for any help I can get :) .

What are file_1 and file_2 supposed to contain?

They are string or Blob parameters (including subclasses such as File) and represent two pdf files uploaded through, say, a form. The link to the doc is
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

I wasn't asking for an explanation what parameters the append method takes, but what exactly they are, in your above code.

Does is still work, if you send body parameter with Postman?

@gre_gor yes it does.

I believe you need to remove the Content-Type header in order to let the browser generate the boundary. BR

So the uploading thing is not specific to Vue.js. You can use JS fetch API.
function handleSubmit(acceptedFiles) {
  const data = new FormData();

  for (const file of acceptedFiles) {
    data.append('files[]', file, file.name);
  }

  return fetch('https://example.com/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,      
  });
}

Also see this - Uploading multiple files with Fetch and FormData APIs

[] at the end for arrays is server specific and as far as I know Spring doesn't support it. Since it works in Postman, there should be no need to change the fileldname.

And I don't see how using fetch instead of Axios, would fix the problem.

Well I found a solution with fetch so shared it. You can find it with axios too.

You never even explained what is wrong with OP's code, so I am not sure what this even solves.
